# Поиск в тексте строки, при помощи слова (буквы) введенного в текстбокс

Tags: pascal, .net, pascalabc.net

Дизайнер форм PascalABC.NET

Вообщем, я хочу сделать что бы при нажатии кнопки был поиск строки по слову, введенного в текстбокс. Естевственно вывод найденной строки будет в другой текстбокс.
Подскажите как можно это оформить.
Есть программа, которую я делал на Л\Р. Не знаю как ее правильно распределить на текстбоксы и кнопки так, что бы небыло ошибок

```
uses crt;
var F:text;
 Str:string; 
 S:string;
begin
clrscr;
assign(f,'D:\1.txt');
reset(f);
write('Введите слово: ');
readln(S);   
while not eof(F) do
   begin
      readln(F,Str);
      if pos(S,Str)>0 then
      writeln(Str);
   end;
close(f);
readln
end.
```

---

Вот кнопка которая у меня:

```
procedure Form4.button1_Click(sender: Object; e: EventArgs);
var F:TextFile;
 Str:string; 
begin
  AssignFile(F,'D:\1.txt');
  reset(F);
  while not eof(F) do
   begin
      readln(F, Str);
      if pos(textbox1.text, Str)>0
      then textbox2.text:= textbox1.text;
   end; 
end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У себя на форме размещаете два текстбокса и кнопку. Создаете процедуру, в которую вписываете приведенный ниже код, и вызываете эту процедуру в обработчике нажатия кнопки. В комментариях я указал старый код, чтобы было видно, что поменялось.

```
var F:TextFile;
 Str:string; 
begin
// clrscr; 
//  assign(f,'D:\1.txt'); если пишите в делфи, то 
AssignFile(f,'D:\1.txt');
reset(f);
// write('Введите слово: ');  это убираем
// readln(S);   
while not eof(F) do
   begin
      readln(F,Str);
      // if pos(S,Str)>0 then это меняем
      if pos(textbox1.text, Str)>0
      // writeln(Str);    
         textbox2.text:= textbox1.text;      
   end;
close(f);
// readln  и это убираем
end;
```

Код работает на Delphi, как обстоят дела в дизайнере форм pascalABC не знаю. Но думаю, что отличия невелики, и перевести код не составит труда.

Comment: а вы begin и end везде правильно поставили?

Comment: Вы код с ошибкой переписали. Вместо `var F:File;` должно быть `var F:TextFile;`

Comment: не read(F, str); а readln(F,Str);  
опять же с ошибкой переписали код

Comment: @teanЫЧ Вроде все работает но не так. В файле есть информация типа "2222222 Максим". Когда я ввожу двойку в первый текстбокс, по идее оно должно мне выбивать во втором текстбоксе "2222222 Максим". Но выдает мне просто "2"
Что не так?

Comment: тогда надо вместо строки:  
textbox2.text:= textbox1.text;  
-----   
написать так:  
textbox2.text:= Str;

Comment: @teanЫЧ спасибо, все работает)
А почему у меня не отображает русские буквы?

Comment: можешь попробовать добавить директиву:  
{$CODEPAGE CP866}    //Устанавливаем кодовую страницу  
-----  
и модуль подключить
uses charset;        //Не обязательно, только
                     //если компилятор выдаёт ошибку

Comment: @teanЫЧ к сожалению директива не помогает а Чарсета попросту нету. Есть еще какие то предложения?
Мониторю форумы - ничего пока не нашел

Comment: @Sin2p
Сохраните свой файл в кодировке Win1251.

Comment: @kot-da-vinci то есть мне нужно просто поменять кодировку файла на win1251? Или как то через Паскаль создать его?